# Python Multiprocessing return results as set in chunksize

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I would like to process a large amount of csv files stored in `file_list` with a function called `get_scores_dataframe`. This function takes a second argument `phenotypes` stored in another list. The function then writes the result back to csv files. I managed to parallelize this task using the `ProcessPoolExecutor()` and as such, it works.

```
   with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        phenotypes = [phenotype for i in range(len(file_list))]
        futures = executor.map(get_scores_dataframe, file_list, phenotypes,
                                    chunksize=25)
        filenames = executor.map(os.path.basename, file_list)
        for future, filename  in zip(futures, filenames):
                futures.to_csv(os.path.join(f'{output_path}',f'{filename}.csv'),
                              index = False)
```

As you can see, I am using a context manager for this and within the context manager the method `map()` where I can set the option `chunksize`. However, I would like that the program writes the csv files as it finishes processing each dataframe. It appears that the context manager waits until all jobs are done and then writes the results to the csv files.

Do you have an idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: I feel writing in same file for every results as when they come, can cause deadlock as many processes will try to write the same file at some point of time.  I experienced this issue while dumping the logs in the log while using multiprocessing.

Comment: `phenotypes = [phenotype for i in range(len(file_list))]` only makes sense if `phenotype` doesn't change. Is that the case. If so, one can use a `partial`, if you make it the first argument (I will explain)

Comment: Yes, phenotype doesn't chage. So it's like a constant dataframe.

Comment: Just an observation: If your dataframe code uses primarily numpy, which uses a log of `C` language code and thus releases the Global Interpreter Lock, then threading may not be a bad alternative. And it's easy to substitute ThreadPoolExecutor for a ProcessPoolExecutor and play around with the `max_workers` argument.

Comment: I have done that with a previous version of the code that worked. It turned out that this process is faster with ProcessPoolExecutor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `executor.map` does not return `Future` instances, so your variable `futures` is poorly named. It does return an iterator that yields the return values of applying `get_scores_dataframe` to each element of `file_list` in turn. Second, seeing how this is used next, it would appear that these return values are input files (which may or may not be the same file as the input argument -- can't be sure from the lack of code shown). Also, using the process pool `map` function rather than the builtin `map` function to get the base name of the filename arguments seems like overkill. Finally, in your code, it would not be `futures.to_csv`, but rather `future.to_csv`. So I am confused as to how your code could have worked at all.

If you modify your function `get_scores_dataframe` to return a tuple consisting of a dataframe and the original passed filename argument, then we can process the results in completion order using `as_competed`:

```
from concurrent.futures import as_completed
import multiprocessing

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(get_scores_dataframe, file, phenotype) for file in file_list]
    for future in as_completed(futures):
        # it is assumed return value is tuple: (data frame, original filename argument):
        df, file = future.result()
        csv_filename = os.path.basename(file)
        df.to_csv(os.path.join(f'{output_path}', f'{csv_filename}.csv'), index = False)
```

Now by using `submit` you are losing the ability to "chunking" up job submissions. We can switch to using `multiprocessing.Pool` with `imap_unordered`. But `imap_unordered` can only pass a single argument to the worker function. So, if you are able to modify your worker to change the order of the arguments, we can make `phenotype` the first one and use a [`partial` (see manual)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=partial#functools.partial):

```
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial


POOL_SIZE = multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1 # leave 1 for main process


def compute_chunksize(iterable_size):
    if iterable_size == 0:
        return 0
    chunksize, extra = divmod(iterable_size, POOL_SIZE * 4)
    if extra:
        chunksize += 1
    return chunksize


with multiprocessing.Pool(POOL_SIZE) as pool:
    chunksize = compute_chunksize(len(file_list))
    worker = partial(get_scores_dataframe, phenotype)
    # it is assumed that start_processing returns a tuple: (data frame, original filename argument)
    for df, file in pool.imap_unordered(worker, file_list, chunksize):
        csv_filename = os.path.basename(file)
        df.to_csv(os.path.join(f'{output_path}', f'{csv_filename}.csv'), index = False)
```

Comment: First, I have added two more solutions. But to answer your question, I wonder if you copied the code correctly because `futures` is not a `set` but rather a `dict` -- note the colon in the following comprehension: `{executor.submit(get_scores_dataframe, file): file for file in file_list}`. The key is `executor.submit(get_scores_dataframe, file)` (a `Future` instance) and its value is `file` and this is iterated for each `file` in `file_list`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your very thourough answer. The `get_scores_dataframe` returns an actual dataframe. Thus, I need to access the argument `file` to get the filename. However, the line `file = futures[file]` throws an error: `TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: I see. Okay, then I have a (hopefully simpler) problem. I actually use two lists that I `zip` in the `get_scores_dataframe`. Thus, it did throw an error with the `:` but not without. How would you write the dict comprehension with two lists of the same size?

Comment: This can be remedied if it returns a tuple consisting of the dataframe and it's original file argument. if it does, you will not need a dictionary. I will update the answers if you give me a couple of minutes.

Comment: `futures = {executor.submit(get_scores_dataframe, file, phenotype): for file, phenotype in zip(file_list, phenotypes)}` is the code I tried. With phenotypes being another list.

Comment: Now you are saying `get_scores_dataframe` takes two arguments?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I wasn't aware that his makes a big difference when I formulated the question. I will update it now

Comment: I am down to two answers, both of which I have modified. See if one or another works and/or which one is faster.

Comment: You are an absolute champ! Thank you so much for taking you time, being patient with a question that wasn't clearly formulated and for modifying it to get it to work. Incredible. Both options work and I will test which one is faster. Again, a sincere thanks.

Comment: Note that I have set the pool size to leave one process for the main process to process the results, i.e. create and write out the CSV file, which I would think is large an I/O bound process. Would it run faster if POOL_SIZE was `multiprocessing.cpu_count()`? I don't know.

Comment: It's a little late now, but I realized that using a dictionary to hold the `Future` instances returned from `ProcessPoolExecutor.submit` in my first solution was perfectly OK.  But the code should have been `file = futures[future]`, that is the key for indexing should have been `future` and not `file`. But you would have needed to modify the worker function to return the original argument for the second solution, anyway.